# a variable defined with let is not defined in a same scope IIFE

Tags: scope, var, let, iife

I have some code below. I hope it can log `a` and `b` correctly, but as the result, it logs `a` as 1, `b` is not defined with error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

```js
function foo(){
    var a = 1
    let b = 2
    (function bar() {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    }())
}
console.log(foo());
```

If I change the code to make the `bar` as a function declaration, every thing is fine

```js
function foo(){
    var a = 1
    let b = 2
    function bar() {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    }
    bar()
}
console.log(foo());
```

I know some thing about function scope, block scope, hoisting. But I really don't understand what happens make the `b` to be 'not defined'

All the code above was run in the Chrome 66's devTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons not to rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) unless you and every programmer who might conceivably work on the code are **very** clear on the rules for ASI.

Your code is trying to call `2` as a function, passing in the result of calling your bar function as an argument, because the `()` around the following IIFE can be reasonably (by ASI rules) considered part of the `let b =` statement. Since calling `bar` happens before `b` is declared (it's not declared until after its initializer runs), you get the error.

If we change the line breaks a bit you can see what's going on:

```js
function foo(){
    var a = 1
    let b = 2(function bar() {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    }());
}
console.log(foo());
```

Adding the `;` fixes it:

```js
function foo(){
    var a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    (function bar() {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
    }());
}
console.log(foo());
```